# In Mysql, how to select two highest values and compare date between then

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's suppose I have two tables: `customers` and `orders`

Orders have these columns:

```
order_created
customer_id
```

Customers have these columns:

```
id
name
email
```

I am trying to build a query to show me the average range of the latest customer orders, for example:

- get two latest orders from all customers (select only customers that have more than 1 order, of course)
- compare the dates and retrieve the average time from o1 to o2 (all customers)

I am not very experienced with MySQL, but so far I have managed to get the max value.

```
select max(o.order_created), c.id, c.name, c.email, 
(date(max(o.order_created)) - date(min(o.order_created))) as date_interval
from orders o
inner join customers c
on c.id = o.customer_id
group by c.id
having date_interval > 0
```

`min` doesn`t work, of course, because I need to retrieve the second max value, not the minimum. And after all that, it needs to retrieve an average value for all this query, which I have no clue how to build.

How can I approach this?

Thanks everybody.

@Edit
I don`t think the duplicate mark solve my question

Comment: The column names in your query don't match the ones you listed above.

Comment: Sorry for that. I've updated

Comment: this boils down to a top-n-per-group query, once you strip off the averaging and whatnot

Comment: Sorry @MarcB But I dont see which answer there solve this only see a lot of link (most external) and even then still will need solve how to calculate the date difference.

Comment: the date difference is basically trivial. the hard part is getting those top-2 records, which isn't directly possible in mysql, since limits aren't supported in subqueries.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry but I disagree, because not sure if will be trivial for OP level. You can look vp answer ... is very close to solve the problem and is very far from a basic query.

Comment: @MarcB Unfortunately I disagree. I tried making and remaking several similar queries outside and inside SO and nothing could help. Happily, vkp is very close to what I desire and i think it is starting making sense. I ask you to please remove the duplicate flag. Juan, I agree with you. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to calculate the row numbers where the latest order per customer gets row number 1 and then calculate the date difference between the latest and the next latest order (for those customers who have atleast 2 orders)

```
select t1.customer_id,
datediff(max(case when rownum=1 then order_date end) ,
         max(case when rownum=2 then order_date end)
        )/2.0 diff
from (select o.*,
      @rn:=if(@previous=customer_id,@rn,0) + 1 as rownum,
      @previous:=customer_id
      from orders o, (select @rn:= 0, @previous:= null) t
      order by customer_id,order_date desc) t1
join (select customer_id from orders group by customer_id having count(*) > 1) t2 
on t1.customer_id=t2.customer_id
group by t1.customer_id
```

Comment: dont you need initialize the variables?

Comment: it would be `null` if i don't initialize it.

Comment: If you don't initialize it, it will be whatever it was last time youi used it.

Comment: All values are retrieving 'null'. Still, it does not return me the average (only a list with several null and customer id). Sorry for the misleading, I have updated the column names

Comment: You need initialize the variables. Check this [**demo**](http://rextester.com/SWBLY55955)

Comment: Juan, the diff number is weird, though. I have added date() as a wrapper around it and the numbers seems to be a little more compatible. I think this is it. Now how can i get the average number of those diff entries? a simple (sum(diff) / count(*)) would do?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza .. you are right.. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @HenriqueM. Not sure what is the final result your need, you should try to provide a more complete description for your problem. Like I did with my demo (db schema, data, current and expected result).

Comment: @HenriqueM. .. because you are selecting 2 rows and computing the difference, average would be the difference/2. see the edited answer.

Comment: I guess if you wrap that subquery with `SELECT avg(diff) from <subquery>` you will get your answer

Comment: Yay! It works (/2.0 diff edit made by vkp)